# filter out post older than custom date field

Tags: php, wordpress, date, conditional-statements

i'm trying to hide posts whereby the custom date field is older than today's date. the way my code is currently set up is to add a class called expired to the LI tag if older but its not playing ball...

```
            <?php 
                wp_reset_query();

                query_posts(array('post_type' => 'events',
                                  'showposts' => 5,
                                  'meta_key'=>'event_date',  
                                  'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
                                  'order' => ASC));
            ?>


            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                                    <?php 

                                        $eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_date'));
                                        $currentdate = date("Ymd");

                                    ?>

                            <li class="<? if ($eventDate < $currentdate) { echo "expired"; } ?>">

                                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                    <span class="date"><strong>Event Date:</strong> <? echo $eventDate->format('d/m/Y'); ?></span>

                            </li>

            <?php endwhile;?>
```

please help me someone:(

Comment: How is your custom date being stored (i.e. what formatting)? Does `get_field('event_date')` definitely work?

Comment: i believe its stored as an integer like 20130223 and then its converted into a readable format 23/02/2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you're comparing a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object against a string - you need to make sure you're comparing equivalent data types:

```
// Convert stored date to DateTime object
$eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_date'));

// Get the current date as a DateTime object
$nowDate = new DateTime();

// And compare them
if ($eventDate == $nowDate) {
   // They're the same, woohoo
} elseif ($eventDate < $nowDate) {
   // Expired
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this now returns an error...
    _italic_ Fatal error: Call to undefined function DateTime() in line 63 _italic_ ... which is...

`$currentDate = DateTime();`

Comment: Sorry, you need to specify `new DateTime()` - try it again

Comment: that works, thank you, but unfortunately i've now just realised because i'm displaying next 5 events, the loop actually display no events now because all the events that are being called in have expired. I guess i need to filter posts older than today instead of adding a class to older posts otherwise new posts will not show.

Comment: @Amesey yeah, it's your call. If there nothing else that you need help on with this question, you can mark it as resolved :)

Comment: i'll mark this as resolved and start a new question, thanks for your help :)